# how to use if else in xquery assignment

Tags: xquery, if-statement, assignment-operator

I am trying to use a if condition to assign a value to a variable in an xquery. I am not sure how to do this.

This is what I tried:

```
declare namespace libx='http://libx.org/xml/libx2';
declare namespace atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';
declare variable $entry_type as xs:string external;
let $libx_node :=
    if ($entry_type = 'package' or 'libapp') then
      {element {fn:concat("libx:", $entry_type)} {()} }
    else if ($entry_type = 'module') then
      '<libx:module>
        <libx:body>{$module_body}</libx:body>
      </libx:module>'
```

This code throws an [XPST0003] Incomplete 'if' expression error. Can someone help me fix this?

Also, can someone suggest some good tutorials to learn xqueries.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because in XQuery's [conditional expression specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-conditionals) **else-expression** is always required:

```
[45]  IfExpr  ::=  "if" "(" Expr ")" "then" ExprSingle "else" ExprSingle
```

So you have to write second `else` clause (for example, it may return empty sequence):

```
declare namespace libx='http://libx.org/xml/libx2';
declare namespace atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';
declare variable $entry_type as xs:string external;

let $libx_node :=
        if ($entry_type = ('package','libapp')) then
          element {fn:concat("libx:", $entry_type)} {()}
        else if ($entry_type = 'module') then
          <libx:module>
            <libx:body>{$module_body}</libx:body>
          </libx:module>
        else ()
... (your code here) ...
```

Some obvious bugs are also fixed:

- don't need {} around computed element constructor;
- most likely, you want `if($entry_type = ('package', 'libapp'))`

Concerning XQuery tutorials. The [W3CSchools's XQuery Tutorial](http://w3schools.com/xquery/default.asp) is a pretty good starting point.