# How to update an XML column in DB2 with XMLQuery?

Tags: db2, sql-update, xquery, xquery-update

**I want to update an XML column in DB2 with dynamic values or you can say with values that I'll pick from another table and insert them in the xml column.**

I know how to insert a node along with its value that we provide by
hard coding it, e.g.

```
<data>some_value</data>
```

I want to do it in the following way:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_table_column = XMLQuery(..... <data>???</data>)
WHERE my_table_id = other_table_id;
```

Where I place `???` I need a kind of select statement here which will come up with actual value for the  node.

Comment: I don't think you need `XMLQUERY()` for that. What "_kind of select statement_" have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: Yes if I've to select the whole value of that column, then yes I don't need XMLQuery.

I need XMLQuery only in the case when I have to traverse within that particular record's xml doc.
**
<root>
<database_systems>
<system name="sys1">123</system>
<system name="sys2">456</system>
<system name="sys3">789</system>
</database_systems>
</root>
**
Now inside this doc we can have any kind of data with random system names. Now I just need to return only this part e.g

**<system name="sys2">456</system>**

instead of whole xml doc, when criteria matched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use if else in xquery assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687218/how-to-use-if-else-in-xquery-assignment)

Comment: @PaulSweatte Thanks Paul. These two are not relevant. I'm thankful to you for your concern. By the way I resolved that issue back at that time. I'll post my answer here as soon as possible. Thanks.